# Postman with WSDL & Authentication

Tags: postman, wsdl

Hi all I have a WSDL endpoint that has basic authentication.  Trying to setup postman by using the link import, which is supposed to read the WSDL and setup everything but there is no place for me to put authentication, so it fails.  Does anyone know an alternative way to setup postman to work with authenticated WSDL?

I tried creating a regular GET request with authentication but that only reads the raw wsdl and doesn't setup all the possible requests etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge and tried:

- `http://username:password@website.com/wsdl`
- `curl -u username:password http://website.com/wsdl`

Neither of which worked. However, simply copy and paste the WSDL schema into the Postman import worked just fine

[image]